# Вертикальное позиционирование SVG-элемента поверх и под другие элементы

Tags: javascript, html, html5, svg, z-index

Нужно, чтобы элемент `rect1` был расположен под `rect2`, но `rect3` (синий) располагался над `rect2` (зелёный) и под `rect1` (красный).

Как можно сделать такое позиционирование?

Далее, мой пример с ошибкой, где `rect3` располагается под `rect2`:

```html
<svg width="350" height="300">
  <rect id="rect3" width="100" height="50" x="75" y="0" fill="blue"/>
  <rect id="rect1" width="100" height="75" x="0" y="0" fill="red"/>
  <rect id="rect2" width="80" height="50" x="0" y="0" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: а как бы помог z-index? условия же взаимоисключающие

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да, это нелогично, я ошибся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SVG позиционирование

Как уже отметили в комментариях `z-index` в svg не поможет. Так как его нет там по определению. Взаимное расположение элементов сродни абсолютному позиционированию: 
*какая строчка кода, определяющая элемент SVG написана последней, тот элемент и будет самым верхним.*
 То есть в вашем случае разноцветные квадраты будут расположены друг над другом в порядке их написания в коде SVG.

В примере ниже, чтобы это было чётко видно, я задал разные размеры квадратам и одинаковые координаты левого, верхнего угла прямоугольников, совпадающими с началом координат SVG полотна. `x="0"` `y="0"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >   
 <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"  fill="red"/>
 <rect id="rect2" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150"  fill="blue"/>
 <rect id="rect3" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"   fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

### CSS позиционирование

Если всё таки хочется применить `z-index` для вертикального позиционирования элементов  SVG, то необходимо каждый элемент SVG обернуть `div`-ами, задать им `pozition:absolute;` и тогда с помощью `z-index` можно регулировать вертикальное расположение прямоугольников.

В примере ниже `z-index:1;` у всех блоков одинаковый, поэтому они располагаются в порядке следования, как в коде

```css
 .wrap {
  position:absolute;
  }
 .red {
  position:absolute;
 top:0;
 
 z-index:1;
 }
 .blue {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 z-index:1;
 }
 .green {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 z-index:1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="red">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >   
    <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300"  fill="red" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >   
 <rect id="rect2" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"  fill="blue"/>
 </svg>
</div> 

<div class="green">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150" >   
 <rect id="rect2" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150"  fill="green" />
 </svg>
</div>

</div>
```

Присваиваем синему квадрату бОльший -`z-index:2;` и он перекроет зелёный квадрат:

```css
.wrap {
  position:absolute;
  }
 .red {
  position:absolute;
 top:0;
 
 z-index:1;
 }
 .blue {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 z-index:2;
 }
 .green {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 z-index:1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="red">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >   
    <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300"  fill="red" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >   
 <rect id="rect2" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"  fill="blue"/>
 </svg>
</div> 

<div class="green">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150" >   
 <rect id="rect2" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150"  fill="green" />
 </svg>
</div>

</div>
```

### JS позиционирование

При наведении курсора на прямоугольник он становится верхним

```js
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
var rects = document.querySelectorAll("rect");

var i = rects.length;
while(i--) {
  rects[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    svg.appendChild(e.target);
  });
}
```

```css
body { 
  background-color: #170A1E; 
  margin: 20px;
  color: gold;
  font-size:18px;
}

svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<p>Наведение курсора меняет вертикальное расположение квадратов</p>
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="dodgerblue" stroke="black"></rect>
  <rect x="125" y="50" width="200" height="200" fill="red" stroke="black"></rect>
  <rect x="50" y="125" width="200" height="200" fill="yellowgreen" stroke="black"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, но как он связан с вопросом, я не понял...

Comment: @Qwertiy Если ты имеешь ввиду вариант JS, то согласен с тобой. Можно рассматривать его как бонус. Остальные варианты, на мой взгляд, вполне подходят

Comment: Неа, вообще. В вопросе спрашивается как сделать какую-то циклическую структуру из наложения трёх блоков, а в ответе про то, что z-index'а нет и как его можно заменить. Но z-index тоже не позволяет сделать циклическую структуру. Я вот попытался подрезать элемент, типа он закрыт, но автор что-то не оценил. А твой ответ вообще с циклической структурой никак не связан. Вот и непонятно...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ты прав, из вопроса вообще было трудно понять, что конкретно нужно автору. Я так понял, что он не подозревал о порядке наложения svg элементов. И разъяснил это первым примером. Второй пример демонстрирует, как всё-таки можно применить z-index `К` - svg, И это довольно распространенный прием с оборачиванием дивами несколько кусков svg c дальнейшим позиционирование CSS

Comment: Просто непонятно, почему циклическая структура наложения в вопросе...

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да, непонятно. Это сейчас не редкость, когда вопрошающие не могут чётко изложить, что же он хотят в самом деле получить. Приходится задавать много уточняющих вопросов. Просто автор экспериментировал с SVG позиционированием и сам не смог понять результаты своих экспериментов Раз принял ответ, значит, что-то всё таки понял из ответов :-)

Answer (score 1):

Красный под синим, синий под зелёным, зелёный под красным:

```html
<svg width="350" height="100">
  <rect id="r-red" width="100" height="75" x="0" y="0" fill="red" />
  <rect id="r-blue" width="100" height="50" x="75" y="0" fill="blue" />
  <rect id="r-green" width="80" height="50" x="0" y="0" fill="green" clip-path="url(#c-blue)" />
  
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="c-blue">
      <use xlink:href="#r-blue" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Но синий над красным, а не под ним. Нужно, чтобы синий прямоугольник как бы "подлез" под промежуток красного и появился на зелёном.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Ты хочешь какую-то муть. Разбирайся.